# What is the spectral family of $ \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0&1&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{array} \right] $?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, projection, orthogonal-matrices

**Spectral Family**:A real spectral family (or real decomposition of unity) is a one parameter family $\mathcal E=(E_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in \mathbb R}$ of projections $E_{\lambda}$ defined on a hilbert space $\mathcal H$ (of any dimension) which depends on a real parameter $\lambda$ and is such that

- $E_{\lambda}E_{\mu}=E_{\mu}E_{\lambda}=E_{\lambda}$[it is given that $\lambda<\mu$]
- $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow-\infty}E_{\lambda}x=0$
- $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}E_{\lambda}x=x$
- $E_{\lambda+0}x=\lim_{\mu\rightarrow\lambda+0}E_{\mu}x=E_\lambda x$

> If an operator $T:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ is represented
> with respect to an orthonormal basis,by a matrix $$ \left[
>  \begin{array}{cc}   0&1&0\\   1&0&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{array} \right] $$
> What is the corresponding spectral family?

Since the spectral family includes eigenvalues so I  computed the eigenvalues of the above matrix which are $\lambda=+1,+1,-1$

I'm not getting how to get the projections corresponding to the eigenvalues{1,1,-1}

need help in getting the spectral family

thank you!

Comment: :$E_{\lambda }$ is the projection onto the sum of eigenspaces of all those eigenvalues of the matrix which does not exceed $\lambda$

Comment: @P.Styles:but here the eigenspaces corresponding to each $\lambda=\pm1$ is {0}.I'm not getting how to write $E\lambda$ explicitly?

Comment: @P.Styles:can it be written as $E_{\lambda=-1}=\{0\}$ and $E_{\lambda=+1}= \{0\}\oplus \{0\}$?